# How to create volume to .net project in Docker?

Tags: .net, docker

Simply said, I published asp.net 6 for linux-x64, selfcontained, single file. And I am trying to create container with link to this project.

When, I create image where I copy the project, it works (see my codes)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime
COPY /app /app 
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./APP"]
```

```
docker run -d -p 8089:80 --name blog-vol blog-img-vol
```

This approach works, however, when I want to use volume for the project, it does not.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./APP"]
```

```
docker run -d -v app:/app -p 8089:80 --name blog-vol blog-img-vol
```

I am getting error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./BlogMVC": stat ./BlogMVC: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Comment: The volume mount hides whatever's in the image, especially including the `/app/APP` executable.  You don't need a volume here; just delete the `docker run -v` option.